# Неоднократное выполнение кода

Tags: php

Благодарю за внимание. Вопрос, собственно говоря, заключается вот в чем. У меня есть цикл. Если условия неверны, мне нужно выполнить одно из возможных условий за пределами цикла(один раз) и снова вернуться к циклу. После отработки цикла, необходимо повторно проверить остальные условия, и снова вернуться к циклу. Так до тех пор, пока возможно выполнение хотя бы одного из условий. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не понятен, по тому, что вы написали, подходит что-то вроде:

```php
$yourCount = 100;

function onFirstIf(){}
function onSecondIf(){}

for ($i = 0; $i<$yourCount;$i++)
{
    if($i == 0) // первая ваша проверка
    {
        onFirstIf();
    }elseif ($i == 1) // вторая ваша проверка
    {
        onSecondIf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ситуация такая. Имеются ресурсы в ограниченном количестве. Так же, есть 2 предприятия, которые изготавливают продукты, исходя из этих ресурсов. В приоритете у каждого сооружения по одному продукту. Всего 3 продукта. Так вот, циклом необходимо пройтись в том случае, если оба предприятия смогут изготовить приоритетные для себя продукты, иначе проверить все возможные условия, если возможно, то один раз изготовить второстепенные продукты и снова вернуться к циклу. И так, до тех пор, пока можно изготовить хотя бы один продукт.

Comment: почитайте про `цепочку зависимостей`

Comment: А если будет множество условий?=))) Вы будете каждый раз добавлять функцию???